# Unable to fetch row data using jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Datatable populating through Java servlet. Once datatable populated, unable to fetch the row data using jquery.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "text",
    url: "DataTableCtrl",
    success: function(data) {
        var jsonTbl = JSON.parse(data, applyCallback);
        var DOMTable = $("<table>").attr("class", "pretty");
        $("#dataTableDiv").append(DOMTable);
        oTable = DOMTable.dataTable(jsonTbl);
    }
});

$('tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    alert('You clicked on ');// failing
});
```

Comment: You need to give more information - what does "failing" and "unable" mean? For example, are you seeing errors or the wrong information?

Comment: If click on any row no action is perfomed.